# String.matches trying to make first letter start with 'K'

Tags: java, string, swing

The comboBox for 'Kansas' gets selected. Then you fill in the textfield  entering your Driver's Licesne number. However, this number must start with the letter 'K' before you enter the following numbers. Is this else if statment incorrect?

```
else if(jComboBox5.getSelectedItem().equals( "KS-Kansas" ) || !uDL.matches("^[K]")) 
        {

            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(jTextField9, "Please enter a correct Driver's License Number!");
        }
```

[image]

Comment: `Is this else if statment incorrect?` - you tell us. Does it do what you want it to do?

Comment: learned I should have been using .startsWith instead of .matches @camickr

Comment: You can [answer your own question](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/17463/163188) or simply delete it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think there might be a better solution to that. Assuming uDL is a String, Java has a function for strings called startsWith(). So you could do this:

```
else if(jComboBox5.getSelectedItem().equals( "KS-Kansas" ) || !uDL.startsWith("K")) 
    {
        //do whatever
    }
```